# Auto text woocommerce_short_description hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements, product

I am trying to create an automatic text in the description of the WooCommerce articles and put "article only available in the store."

I thought about putting it inside a function like this:

```
add_filter ('woocommerce_short_description', 'in_single_product', 10, 2);

function in_single_product () {
    echo '<p> my-text-here </ p>';
}
```

But the text does not appear in the front-end. It only appears if I put the text on the back-end.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Correct **syntax for writing add_filter**

```
// Define the my_editor_content  
function my_editor_content( $post_excerpt )   {  
    // make filter magic happen here...
    return $post_excerpt;
};
// add the filter
add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description','my_editor_content',10, 1 );
```

Well, you could use this code in **functions.php** of your child theme.

```
function my_editor_content( $post_excerpt ) {
$content = 'The default text, imposed by me, needs to be here in every product.';
return $content.'<br>'.$post_excerpt;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_short_description', 'my_editor_content', 10, 1);
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 4):

Use a conditional for single product pages and return the function variable instead of echoing it.

This will replace the post excerpt in single product pages:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description', 'single_product_short_description', 10, 1 );
function single_product_short_description( $post_excerpt ){
    global $product;

    // compatibility with WC +3
    $product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id;

    if ( is_single( $product_id ) )
        $post_excerpt = '<p class="some-class">' . __( "my-text-here", "your_theme_slug" ) . '</ p>';

    return $post_excerpt;
}
```

Is better to ad your text in a gettex for translation (replace `"your_theme_slug"` by the slug of your theme...

Reference: [How to use different short description in shop page and in product page in woocommerce](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/98251/79855)

Comment: Thank you very much for answering!

I tried the code and it works very well, although in this case I used to replace the text in the short descriptions. If there is no short description of the product, the text does not appear.

It is possible to display the text of the code without having a short description of the product?

Thank you very much

Comment: thank you and sorry!
Here is the link of my new question :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38098914/automatic-text-in-short-description-of-woocommerce-products
i hope have done well!